# Dual viewport, one shows cam view only

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm sure this is pretty simple, I'm running Blender on 2 screens, and one of thos 2 viewport recently decided to work only from camera perspective, all other views are empty.

Edit: 2.93.2, Win 10

What did and what can I do?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like to know what happened, but I just closed that instance and dragged over another one. Now it works just fine again. I'm just leaving this here for future reference ;-)